# how to change the entered text font family value dynamically?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a very simple doubt, I have a input text and a drop down list and in that drop down list their are various font family, so if I enter any text in the input field and later if I select the font family from the dropdown list as arial then the entered text should be displayed in arial font. Please can any one guide me I'm very much close to completing the task.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>

                <style>

                </style>

            </head>

            <body style="padding-left:200px">

                <?php

                    $name = $font = $size = "" ;

                    if (isset($_POST["font"])) {
                        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                        $font = test_input($_POST["font"]);
                        var_dump($font);
                        $size = test_input($_POST["size"]);
                        var_dump($size);
                    }

                    function test_input($data) {
                        return $data;
                    }

                    ?>

                <form action="" method="post">

                    <br><br>

                    <div>

                        <label style="color:orange">Enter Text: </label> <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Something">

                    </div><br><br>

                    <div>

                        <label style="color:orange">Select Size: </label> <input type="text" name="size">

                    </div><br><br>

                    <div>

                        <label class="control-label" style="color:orange;">Font Name :</label>

                        <select name="font" style="margin-left:14px; color:black;">

                            <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                            <option>Times New Roman</option>
                            <option>Arial</option>
                            <option>Verdana</option>
                            <option>Georgia</option>
                            <option>Impact</option>

                        </select>

                    </div><br><br>

                    <!--div>

                        <label style="color:orange">Choose Color: </label> <input type="text" name="size">

                    </div><br><br-->

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  

                </form>

                <?php

                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "<h2 style='color:orange'>OUTPUT:</h2>";
                    echo '<p style="font-family:'.$font.'; font-size:'.$size.';">'.$name.'</p>';


                ?>

            </body>
         </html>
```

Comment: can you use jquery ? Form submission must ?

Comment: sir if its in php it would be better sir

Comment: im very close sir to complete please help me sir

Comment: What have you tried? Don't see any code related to font/class changing. Define 5 CSS-classes for your fonts, apply the class to your text when the `<select>` changes

Comment: sir that only im not getting how to change please can u help me please sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Just echo your font variable in the variable you are echoing.
Put the value returning font in a variable and use that variable while you echo.

```
if (isset($_POST["font"])) {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    $font = test_input($_POST["font"]);
} 

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>

                    <style>
                        .error {
                            color: #FF0000;
                            }
                    </style>

                </head>

                <body style="padding-left:200px">

                    <?php

                        $name =  "";
                        $font='arial';
                        $size='14px';
                        if (isset($_POST["font"])) {
                            $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                            $font = test_input($_POST["font"]);
                            $size = test_input($_POST["size"]);
                        }

                        function test_input($data) {
                            return $data;
                        }

                        ?>

                    <form action="" method="post">

                        <br><br>

                        <div>

                            <label style="color:orange">Enter Text: </label> <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Something">

                        </div><br><br>



                        <div>

                            <label class="control-label" style="color:orange;">Font Name :</label>

                            <select name="font" style="margin-left:14px; color:black;">

                                <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                                <option>Times New Roman</option>
                                <option>Arial</option>
                                <option>Verdana</option>
                                <option>Georgia</option>
                                <option>Impact</option>

                            </select>

                        </div><br><br>



                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  

                    </form>

                    <?php

                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<h2 style='color:orange'>OUTPUT:</h2>";
                        echo '<p style="font-family:'.$font.';font-size:'.$size.';">'.$name.'</p>';


                    ?>

                </body>
             </html>
```

Comment: Happy to help. Good day@kumarpatil

Comment: sir what if i want to change the size.

Comment: as i changed the font family if i want to change the font size what i should do sir?

Comment: Put `$size = test_input($_POST["size"]);` in your isset check and echo font-size varible where you echo the variable. `echo '<p style="font-family:'.$font.';font-size:'.$size.';">'.$name.'</p>';`@kumarpatil

Comment: sir i did but its not working please see my updated post

Comment: @kumarpatil you haven't added input field for font-size

Comment: sir i did not got u

Comment: You have added drop down for font-family. Like wise you have to add another input field for font-size with name `size`@kumarpatil

Comment: sir i want it in text field not drop down,

Comment: how to do it sir?.

Comment: @kumarpatil Just check my answer. I have edited my answer. it's working

Comment: @kumarpatil We are always happy to help. A small advice. Don't feel bad for me.  Googling helps self learning. Try to google and then use stackoverflow.

Comment: i did not felt bad